# AWS Datalake Formation MySQL Blueprint error with incompatible sql_mode only_full_group_by

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, data-lake

Using AWS DataLake Formation blueprint to import a MySQL DB to S3. Used the stock blueprint to import the data. But the job failed with below error and stack trace.

`Expression #4 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'DBName.TTT.Num' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by`

I know I can workaround the issue by disabling the 'full group by' in my MySQL DB. But shouldnt the AWS guys be knowing not to include columns in select clause that are not in group by, or add all the columns in select clause to group by?

Also, why is it happening to only a few tables, but not all?

Any AWS internal DataLake devs nearby?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script_2020-01-13-17-14-42.py", line 320, in <module>
    main()
  File "script_2020-01-13-17-14-42.py", line 316, in main
    driver.run_transform()
  File "script_2020-01-13-17-14-42.py", line 297, in run_transform
    transform.transform()
  File "script_2020-01-13-17-14-42.py", line 90, in transform
    self._snapshot_transform()
  File "script_2020-01-13-17-14-42.py", line 78, in _snapshot_transform
    table_name=self.source.table_name)
  File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/root/appcache/application_1578935347236_0001/container_1578935347236_0001_01_000001/PyGlue.zip/awsglue/dynamicframe.py", line 611, in from_catalog
  File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/root/appcache/application_1578935347236_0001/container_1578935347236_0001_01_000001/PyGlue.zip/awsglue/context.py", line 142, in create_dynamic_frame_from_catalog
  File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/root/appcache/application_1578935347236_0001/container_1578935347236_0001_01_000001/PyGlue.zip/awsglue/data_source.py", line 36, in getFrame
  File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/root/appcache/application_1578935347236_0001/container_1578935347236_0001_01_000001/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1257, in __call__
  File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/root/appcache/application_1578935347236_0001/container_1578935347236_0001_01_000001/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
    print("[INFO] GRANTed Select permission to 
{}
 on table 
{}
::
{}
".format(creator_arn, db_name, table_name))
  File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/root/appcache/application_1578935347236_0001/container_1578935347236_0001_01_000001/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o1287.getDynamicFrame.
: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Expression #4 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'DBName.TTT.Num' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:377)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:360)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:978)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3887)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3823)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2435)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2582)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2530)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1907)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:2030)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.jdbc.glue.GlueJDBCSource$.resolveTable(GlueJDBCSource.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.jdbc.glue.GlueJDBCSource$.createRelation(GlueJDBCSource.scala:30)
    at com.amazonaws.services.glue.util.JDBCWrapper.tableDF(JDBCUtils.scala:805)
    at com.amazonaws.services.glue.util.NoCondition$.tableDF(JDBCUtils.scala:84)
    at com.amazonaws.services.glue.util.NoJDBCPartitioner$.tableDF(JDBCUtils.scala:123)
    at com.amazonaws.services.glue.JDBCDataSource.getDynamicFrame(DataSource.scala:745)
    at com.amazonaws.services.glue.DataSource$class.getDynamicFrame(DataSource.scala:77)
    at com.amazonaws.services.glue.SparkSQLDataSource.getDynamicFrame(DataSource.scala:586)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor107.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```